# Possible issues with embedding functions inside functions in python. Are there times when this should be avoided?

Tags: python, function

If you define a function in your python script and later want to use this function and possibly others inside a different function would this always work or are there any cases where this might cause issues? Also is there ever a case where this is considered bad practice?

*E.g*

Say I define a simple function to square a number and then use this function inside a function to some those square numbers, this seems to work however are there any cases with more complex functions where this could cause an issue (embedding functions inside functions).

```
def square(a):
    c = a**2
    return c

square(2)



def sum_of_squares(d,e):
    x = square(d) + square(e)    # Using the square function defined earlier
    return x

sum_of_squares(2,4)
```

**Note** Not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question so feel free to move it if so.

Comment: Calling a function in another function doesn't have any problem, and this is actually the reason that functions are introduced, to move the duplicate code into them and make the code reusable.

Comment: You're not 'embedding' a function inside another, you're calling it from inside another function. it's not really any different functionally to calling print() from inside a function.  If you had a function defined outside a class then called it from a class that might be a bad idea, because you can't then over-ride that 'global' function, but that might be preferable depending on the situation.

Comment: It seems that with "embedding" a function you mean *calling* a function from within another function. This is a standard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not only you can call functions in other functions, but the function itself inside the same function known as `recursion`. Check out this function of calculating a `factorial` as an example of recursion.

```
def factorial(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n * factorial(n-1)
```

So there isn't any case where calling a function inside other function (or same) would fail provided you are using the right syntax:)